# How to send stream to ServiceStack? (RequestStream always has zero length when using IRequiresRequestStream)

Tags: http, servicestack

I am trying to implement streamed uploads using ServiceStack.

I followed the streaming uploads example linked from ServiceStack wiki (http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/501608/Sending-Stream-to-ServiceStack).

The problem is that on the Service side, the request stream is always empty (Length=0).

Same applies for `base.Request.InputStream` accessed in the Service processing the POST method (actually the stream instances are the same for Request.InputStream and the IRequiresRequestStream.RequestStream property).

Documentation does not provide any more information either:

https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Serialization-deserialization#reading-directly-from-the-request-stream

**EDIT: It works when using the exact solution from codeproject which uses console based AppHost. It does not work when using ASP.NET host.**

**How to properly access the request stream using ServiceStack?**

Comment: Are you trying to upload a File? If you could post some code you are using that would be helpful. The sample code from CodeProject.com is working for me.

Comment: I am using the exact code from codeproject.

Comment: I tried running the solution from codeproject as is and I can see the difference is in how the app is being hosted. Mine is hosted in ASP.NET (debugging in VS webserver), the codeproject solution is using the console based AppHost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After long hours of debugging and analyzing the differences, I found out that the issue is with the VS Web Development server. Switching to IIS Express in Visual Studio settings fixed the issue - the RequestStream is not empty anymore.

To change the setting, go to `Project properties` -> `Web` tab, under Servers, pick `Use Local IIS Web server` instead of the default `Use Visual Studio Development Server`